# How to search documents and fetch the items that reference them

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 schemas:

```
Order = {
  name: String,
  products: [{
    id: ObjectId,
    qty: Number,
    sheet: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Sheet' }
 }]
}

Sheet: {
  code: String
}
```

I would like to query the sheets and get a list of all the products that are referencing them (the sheet). I would like to do this in real time (meaning no cron aggregation thingy) - what would be the recommended approach?

1) Also add a ref to the order/product in Sheet and update that at the same time as I add the ref in order

2) Perform a subquery for each retrieved Sheet

3) Some other fantastic mongo way?

Comment: Considering that 1 and 2 are virtually the same thing because population hits the DB twice under the covers – I think you've answered your own question, no?

Comment: @jibsales possibly - learning the inner workings of Mongo and discovering new tricks all the time - was hoping there was one here :)